# Lagrangian equation for a force applied to symmetric configuration consisting of two masses. Each mass connected to a spring

Tags: classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

This is the configuration for which I have to write system dynamics.

[Lagrangian question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUsXH.png)

This is my attempt:

T = $\frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{x}^2\right) + \frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{x}^2\right)$

U = $\frac{1}{2}k(x\cos(\theta))^2 + \frac{1}{2}k(x\cos(\theta))^2 - \frac{1}{2}mgL\sin(\theta) - \frac{1}{2}mgL\sin(\theta)$

Is my Lagrangian correct? I am assuming that both springs are displaced by a distance x from their undeformed position

**Edit:** I went back and tried a new approach. This time I assigned coordinates to the midpoint of both masses with respect to the middle point of the configuration. Then I use those coordinates (in terms of the angle theta) and the extension of the springs from the undeformed position (denoted as x) to compute the kinetic and potential energy

[second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vezTb.jpg)

Comment: This is physics, not mathematics. Only self gratification here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Here we have an one dimensional dynamic system that can be modeled according to

$$
T = 2\left(\frac 12\dot x^2+\frac 12 J\dot\theta^2\right)\\
V = 2\left(\frac 12 k x^2\right)+2L m g\sin\theta
$$

where $J$ is the inertia moment for bar $L$ regarding the mass center and also

$$
y=L\sin\theta\\
x=L\cos\theta\\
\dot y = L\cos\theta\dot\theta\\
\dot x = -L\sin\theta\dot\theta
$$

now with $L = T-V$ we have

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\theta}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial\theta} = \frac{\partial W}{\partial\theta} = \frac{\partial( F y)}{\partial\theta} = L F \cos\theta
$$